# Outputting certain Facebook JSON elements to a file in Python in Reverse

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, facebook, parsing

I'm trying to take the JSON output from Facebook Messages
and output certain elements to a TXT file in
chronological order. Facebook outputs in Reverse Chronological Order.

I would like to output the Date, Sender and Content each to a line.

I have this code, but it's throwing this error: KeyError: 'message'

```
import json
import datetime

with open("message_1.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

dataarray = []

for doc in data['message']:
    epochdatetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(doc['timestamp_ms'])
    linetowrite = epochdatetime + ' ' + doc['sender_name'] + ': ' + doc['content'] + '/r/n'
    dataarray.append(linetowrite)


i = len(data) - 1

openfile = open('messages.txt','w')

while i >= 0 :
    openfile.write(dataarray[i]) 
    i -= 1

openfile.close()
```

This is one sample element from the JSON file. Having trouble with Nested JSON.

```
{
    "participants": [
      {
        "name": "Person 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Person 2"
      }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
          "sender_name": "Person 2",
          "timestamp_ms": 1631383988779,
          "content": "Hi, how are you?",
          "type": "Generic",
          "is_unsent": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import json
import datetime


with open('message_1.json', 'r') as input_stream, open('messages.txt', 'w+') as output_stream:
    json_data = json.load(input_stream)

    messages = map(lambda x: f'{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x.get("timestamp_ms") / 1000)} '  # ms to s
                             f'{x.get("sender_name")}: {x.get("content")}\n', 
                             json_data['messages'])

    for line in reversed(list(messages)):
        output_stream.write(line)
```

Output with the provided JSON sample

```
2021-09-11 20:13:08.779000 Person 2: Hi, how are you?
```

Keep in mind that maybe you want to set another tz or a date format for your output date field. More info on datetime module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)